# How should a page perform incremental load as data becomes available from the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a table on my page, each row representing a model entity.  Each cell of each row requires a web request to be made to a 3rd party server in order to obtain the information to populate the cell.  The previous developer decided since there were only ~20 cells that having a single Ajax request per-cell was the correct approach to solving this.  I believe that the proper way would be to use a single ajax request for the page, and then receive a multi-part response as the data becomes available, populating the table accordingly.

How should this be done?

I'm most concerned with the javascript side of things, but if anyone wants to provide a controller action sample in ASP.NET MVC 5 that would be awesome as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the volatility of the data coming from the 3rd party services, I would create a service that would proxy and aggregate the calls to the 3rd party.  The idea is to collect the values from the 3rd party, optimize the returned data (cache, aggregate, etc) and then expose it to your web application via an ajax.

If you can't realistically aggregate the result, you might want to take a look at `SignalR` to incrementally push the data up to your web application.  Telerik has a nice tutorial that sounds similar to yours: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/signalr

Comment: So the idea here would be less responses from the service unless using Web sockets via SignalR?

Comment: Precisely. That and by aggregating the data on your own server, you can cache the data to serve it even faster.

Comment: 1 minute is considered stale data here.  Caching isn't really viable.